# DynamoDBMappingException could not unconvert attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, quarkus

I'm having trouble converting a List object and it's returning the error below:

```
expected S in value {L: [{M: {txt_just={S: new client,}, num_funl={S: 123,}, num_propt={S: 2f1a8e6c-68bb-4c26-9326-3823d9f96c4c,}, ind_decs={S: S,}, dat_hor={S: 20220721183000,}},}],}
```

My Class translator:

```
public class ObjectTranslators<T> implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, T> {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convert(T t) {
        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(t);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to parse JSON");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T unconvert(String s) {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(s, new TypeReference<>() {});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to read JSON");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to convert a List that has a single entry which is a Map of 5 key/value pairs. Your real issue is probably that there is no value supplied to `ind_decs` but, it's also possible that you aren't properly using the expected generic T type wherever ObjectTranslators is used as well.

```
expected S in value 

{
    L: [
        {
            M: {
                txt_just={S: new client,}, 
                num_funl={S: 123,}, 
                num_propt={S: 2f1a8e6c-68bb-4c26-9326-3823d9f96c4c,}, 
                ind_decs={S: S,}, 
                dat_hor={S: 20220721183000,}
            },
        }
    ],
}
```